# How do I get a video to fit in a specified area?

Tags: html, css, video, html5-video

How would I go about fitting a video to a specified area? I'm trying to fit my 960px by 500px `video` to fit into the corresponding matching area, but when I try to it's doing this:

[image]

I'd like to have the video fit into the red area.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="mainvideo">
<video width="960" height="500" controls>
<source src="videos/moikitvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="videos/moikitvideo.webm" type="video/webm">
 Your browser does not support the video tag.
</source>
</source>
</video>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
#mainvideo{
  width: 960px;
  height: 500px;
  float:left;
  margin-top:10px;
  background-color:#75A96F;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is due to padding. Without a jsfiddle or anything I can't really tell though. Try this:

```
#mainvideo{
  width: 960px;
  height: 500px;
  float:left;
  margin-top:10px;
  background-color:#75A96F;
  padding: 0;
}
```

This could also be due to the video ratio itself. I wouldn't worry about the height and focus on the width. Make sure the width fits and allow the height to scale. So set height to 100% or auto once you have the video fitting perfectly width wise.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple things you can do.  First change your width and height of your video to 100% so your video player fills the mainvideo container.  Next, set your padding and margins to 0px in your CSS.  Finally, you do not need the "" since it is not an element.  Below is the code that I altered.  Best of luck!

HTML

```
<div id="mainvideo">
    <video width="100%" height="100%" controls>
    <source src="videos/moikitvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="videos/moikitvideo.webm" type="video/webm">
     Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#mainvideo{
    width: 960px;
    height: 500px;
    float:left;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px
    background-color:#75A96F;
}
```

Comment: The "" in my post are supposed to be "/source".